# How can I express that an object property is the negation of another?

Tags: owl, protege, owl-api

How can I express that an object property is the negation of another ?, for example, in geographical domain the spatial relationship "disjoint" is the negation of "intersects", the same happens between "isFarOf" and "isNearOf".

I know that there is "NegativeObjectPropertyAssertion" (see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/), but that only allows me to express particular cases at the level of relationships between two individuals, I need something like that but that I would level of object properties.

For example, in the same way that I can say that "isEastOf" is the inverse of "isWestOf", I would like to be able to say that "disjoint" is the negation of "intersects" or that "isFarOf" is the negation of "isNearOf"

I would also like to know how I do it in a Protégé tool.

Greetings.

Comment: Short answer, this is not possible in OWL 2 DL. The reason for is that it is based on the description logic SROIQ. afaik, this is even not possible in SWRL

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have no choice but to simulate it by using "NegativeObjectPropertyAssertion" with all the pairs of individuals belonging to the two classes.

Greetings.

Comment: Returning to this question, it occurs to me to say that "disjoint" is the inverse of the negation of "intersects". Would this statement be correct?

Greetings

Comment: I have noticed that the pairs of properties of analyzed objects ("isFarOf" --- "isNearOf" and "disjoint" --- "intersects"), besides being disjointed, do not admit more than two possible answers. That is to say, it can be affirmed that for each pair of spatial objects the following affirmations are fulfilled: 1) Or they are disjointed, or they intersect. 2) Or are far away, or are near.   

Note that this is not true for all pairs of properties of objects that are disjointed.